# FileTransfer returning error code null with cordova 3.0.0

Tags: file, file-upload, null, cordova-3

I am creating a photo upload app with cordova 3.0.0.
I have the following upload code:
 // Upload files to server

```
 function uploadFileForCapture(mediaFile) {
        var ftforcapture = new FileTransfer(),
            path = mediaFile.fullPath,
            name = mediaFile.name;
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="fname";
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
            ftforcapture.upload(path,
            "http://abc.efg.com/cordovademo/upload.php",
            function(result) {
                alert('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
                alert(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
            },
            function(error) {
                alert('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
            },
            { fileName: name },optionas);
    }
```

It returns an error code of null.
Can someon please help me out!
Thanks

Comment: The correct answer is Kishor Subedi's down below.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the parameter options spelled wrong as the last parameter of the upload() method.

Change

```
optionas
```

To

```
options
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a long time ago you asked the question, but I ran into the same problem and found the solution. Maybe it helps:

You have to add the cordova FileTransfer explicitly (this is NOT included in File). So you have to execute

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
```

and

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
```

You can find all the details here: [Cordova docs - File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html)